# async.parallel`s function is working after another function has invoked callback function with error, why?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

i was learning async library and just tried some codes myself and i am issueing a problem that can`t handle, can you please look at the code down below:)

```
    async.parallel([
    function (cb) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          let a = "asd";

          console.log("AAA");
          cb(a, null);

        }, 2000);
    },
    function (cb) {
      setTimeout( () => {
        let b = "dasd";

        console.log("BBBBB");
        cb(b, null);
      }, 5000);
    }
  ], function (error, results) {
    console.log("CCC");

    console.log("Errors: " + error);
    console.log("Results: " + results);
  });
```

I supposed that BBB should NOT output to the screen, but to my surprise it DOES, can you help me understand why?

Comment: Why do you think `BBBBB` would not be output?

Comment: because, the doc says that If any of the functions pass an error to its callback, the main callback is immediately called with the value of the error.

Comment: Ok, I see. That's true, but the `setTimeout` still gets called after 5 seconds regardless.

Comment: exactly, why?????????????

Comment: just, i wanted to check if the new user`s email and username are not taken by someone else in async.parallel but doesn`t work

Answer (score 2):

You are using `async.parallel()`. All asynchronous tasks will be executed without waiting for each other and the execution order is not guaranteed.

Here's a breakdown on how your script is executed:

1. Both `setTimeout()` are set.
2. 2000 milliseconds later, `console.log("AAA")` and `cb(a, null)` are called.
3. `cb(a, null)` has an error. So the main callback is called, and `async.parallel()` ends.
4. But the story does not end here. The second `setTimeout()` is already set. Calling the main callback will not clear the timeout.
5. `console.log("BBBBB")` and `cb(b, null)` are called. This is why you see the output `BBBBB`.
6. Because the main callback is already called, calling `cb(b, null)` will not do anything.